# ASP.NET Markup Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-3.5, intellisense, markup

When I type `<` in the Markup Mode of Visual Studio 2010, I don't get any server-side controls (ie. `<asp:textbox />`), I just get a list of standard HTML controls.

This used to work, but one day just stopped.

Why could this be?

P.S: I'm a VB.NET Programmer, and intellisense is working fine in the .vb files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Navigate here:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio

And delete the contents of the folder labeled '10.0'. This worked for me.

Comment: I'm unable to find an 'AppData' folder in my [USERNAME] folder?

Comment: Curt, its a hidden folder, so you won't see it in the folder list. (based on your WinExplorer settings I think). Just type in  "C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData" and it will magically appear.

Comment: Cheers Graham, folders currently empty, but then intellisense is working at the moment. When it starts messing up again, I'll give this a try!

Comment: made the change in c:\users\username\appdata and it didn't do anything. However when I went to %appdata% it took me to a network share, and deleting from there did work.

Comment: Note to anyone deleting this folder: If you delete the entire folder contents it will reset most of your workspace preferences(pinned sections)

Comment: Does anyone know what in that folder is causing the problem?

Comment: @Graham I also have the same problem: Visual Studio 2010. No intellisense in aspx markup, but have intellisense in the code behind cs files. Deleted the contents in the said folder, but problem remains.

Answer (score -1):

- Check *file extension - editor* bindings in preferences.
- Check the **system.web\pages\controls** config section in your web configuration file.
- Check the **system.web\compilation\assemblies** section too.