# VStudio 2010 - ASP.NET - I lose Intellisense within various tags (markup)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

**I get no intellisense in the following lines of code (see MyStore.CustomerID):**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" Text="<%# MyStore.CustomerID %>" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" Text='<%# MyStore.CustomerID %>' />
<a href="<%# MyStore.CustID %>"></a>
```

**But, I do get it here:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" Text="blank" />
<%# MyStore.CustomerID %>
```

**How do I turn on intellisense within these other tags?**

I really would like to set text/value of various controls from within the markup to clear up space in the code-behind.

**Note**

Not the same issue as [ASP.NET Markup Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310526/asp-net-markup-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: my solution is this : I am writing the code inside code nuggets separate from html markup so I get intellisense. after that I cut the code and put it where it belongs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is a case also for me. When you are working with code nuggets (<%:...%>), you get intellisense when they are separate from any other HTML attributes. but when you work with them inside a HTML attribute, you get no intellisense.

So you didn't lose it, it hasn't been there at all.

here is a quote;

> Unforunately code IntelliSense is not
>   supported in code nuggets that are
>   within HTML attributes in Web Forms
>   files. This is supported in Razor
>   (CSHTML) files however.

see this one as well;

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/617937/intellisense-uses-wrong-context-on-c-nuggets-in-asp-net-mvc2-views