# Visual Studio 2012. Object does not exists, yet project builds fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a problem with 1 of the aspx files in my project, I hope someone have some idears how to fix it.

I keep getting

> object does not exists in the current context

on all controls, but when I build the project it builds without errors.

If I try typing somthing in the code behind after the build, then Visual studio marks all controls from the mark up as "object does not.."

Even all `document.getElementById('<%=specificControl.ClientID%>').value` in the mark up are marked as "object does not exists..."

I tried creating a new aspx file, with a different name, but the same issue was present if I copied the markup and code behind content to that.

Comment: If I look in the designer file, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the code behind file name and Inherits property on the @Page directive don't match.Both should match.

Comment: Just checked, everything is correct, and the project builds without errors.

Comment: I am using master page, and after I supplied a specific ID to the Content holder the errors went away. Problem is that now the Autocomplete intellisense does not work for this specific file :-/

Comment: try this SO tip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310526/asp-net-markup-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I managed to confuse Visual Studio or somthing. As I said it did build without problems, but after renaming the class for the current page I was having issues with, then everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by selecting Debug option from drop-down list it is selected as release.