# ContentPlaceHolder not supported

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This my ASPX File

```
<%@ Page Title="Extra Virgin Olive Oil From Argos" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Production.master"
    AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="acova.aspx.vb"  Inherits="pages_products_evoo_acova" %>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head2" runat="server" ID="Contnet0">
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32158435-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftHolder2" runat="server" ID="Content2">
    <%= IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("../../../pages/announce/AdSense01.htm"))%>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderID="RightHolder2" runat="server" ID="Content3">
    <%= IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("../../../pages/announce/GoogleAdd.htm"))%>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentCenter" Runat="Server" ID="Content1"> 
    <!--   START Code Here    -->
    <!-- <div id="Div1" class=" Style_Center" runat="server"> -->
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" class="PanelStyle3" ScrollBars="Vertical">
```

At this positon the asp:Content... and the asp:panel.... produces an error

> Element "ContentPlaceHolder is not supported

That error was not from the beginning when i start to work with Visual Studio 2010. I see thatfew months ago and I didn't pay any attention because evrything worked fine.
But now is very much a noising, and I want to eliminate.

This is the Production.Master file which is under the MaterPage.master File

```
    <%@ Master  Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" ID="Content0" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder  EnableViewState="true" ID="head2" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ButtonsPH" ID="Content1" runat="server">

    <!--  Buttons  -->
    <div  id="tabsF">
     <h3>
            <a id="A1" href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server" target='_parent'><span>Home</span></a>

</h3>
                </div>

    <!-- END Buttons -->
</asp:Content>
```

Now here the First Content it works without Validation error but the second gives this Validation error.
The Left and Right Holders are in MaserPage.maser file
Same happen in MasterPage.master File

Comment: Please paste your complete html code.

Comment: Make sure you are using a [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX) which has been correctly setup.

Comment: @Saad Khatri I did paste the code from Production.master File

Comment: @Malice it is defently certain that i use it properly because a year ago i didn't have any issues to face, issues like that i mean. the all code was working fine, and now is working fine exept this Validation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just put another question with more details and from there i had my answer

Answer (score 0):

The parent master page should define `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` controls. Those content placeholder controls should be referenced by corresponding `<asp:Content>` controls in the child master page.

If the child master page in turn defines any `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` controls then the ASPX page that references the child master page will need to reference those content placeholders with corresponding `<asp:content>` controls.

**Parent.master**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
```

**Child.master**

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceholderID="MainContent" runat="server">
...
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ChildContent1" runat="server" />
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceholderID="ChildContent1" runat="server">
   <p>Text goes here</p>
</asp:Content>
```

A complete example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For your given example, make sure you have `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` controls defined for the `<asp:content>` controls with ContentPlaceHolderID values of "head" and "ButtonsPH".

In your ASPX file you are referencing `<asp:content>` controls with ContentPlaceHolderID values of "LeftHolder2", "RightHolder2" and "ContentCenter" but there are no corresponding `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` controls defined in Production.master.

Comment: I have checks all the correspondence in all Master and child master and aspx files. But issues are begin when I’m trying to type <asp: then there is no any predefined words or the asp: itself

Comment: The problem is that is not accepting <asp: after the firts one at the top of the file.

Comment: @LefterisGkinis: That sounds like it could be a separate issue. Usually when something like that happens to me I restart Visual Studio and the problem goes away. There is also a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3310526/137001) which might help you.

Comment: I just upload another question with this Phenomenon